# Aggregate and annotate on relation to self

Tags: django, django-models

If I have this model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=28)
  mother=models.ForeignKey(self,null=True,blank=True)
```

I am trying to make a query, where I add an annotaion that includes the number of children each of the Person objects have. Is this possible? Or do I need to add an integerField that manually keeps records of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
Person.objects.annotate(child_count=Count('person'))
```

Comment: Thanks. If I add a field grandMother, which also is a refference to Person, is there a way to distinguish the children from the grandchildren of a person?

Comment: You'd need to use a `related_name` attribute. However if you're going to store multiple levels, you'd be better off using something like [MPTT](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/).